# pandas save to_csv with quote for thousand separator

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I would like to save an excel sheet to CSV with this format for numeric :

Cash at Bank; 102.682,35   ;;;;

It could be like this:

```
data_xls.to_csv('your_csv.csv', encoding='utf-8', sep=";", thousands='.')
```

unfortunately thousand=',' does not exist as parameter :-)

this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd


data_xls = pd.read_excel('TSophie.xlsm', 'Import File', index_col=None)
print(data_xls['Amount'].dtype)
print(data_xls.head)

data_xls.to_csv('your_csv.csv', encoding='utf-8', sep=";", thousands=',')
```

Sample of CSv:

```
Entity;Currency;Year;Period;Scenario;View;IC;Origin;Flow B;UD1;Bucket;BU;Flow PL;Account;ACC+Bucket;Description;Amount;;;;
TDBNL_LE;Local;2020;M03;Actual;YTD;None;Import;M999;LocalGL;None;C2_2070;None;10010;10010None;Petty Cash; -     ;;;;
TDBNL_LE;Local;2020;M03;Actual;YTD;None;Import;M999;LocalGL;None;C2_2070;None;10020;10020None;Payment in Transit; -     ;;;;
TDBNL_LE;Local;2020;M03;Actual;YTD;None;Import;M999;LocalGL;None;C2_2070;None;10030;10030None;Suspense Account; -     ;;;;
TDBNL_LE;Local;2020;M03;Actual;YTD;None;Import;M999;LocalGL;None;C2_2070;None;10040;10040None;Cash at Bank; 102.682,35   ;;;;
TDBNL_LE;Local;2020;M03;Actual;YTD;None;Import;M999;LocalGL;None;C2_2070;None;10500;10500None;Non-Operational Cash; -     ;;;;
TDBNL_LE;Local;2020;M03;Actual;YTD;None;Import;M999;LocalGL;None;C2_2070;None;14000;14000None;Work in Progress -PS; 12.677,90   ;;;;
```